# How to write pseudo parameters in troposphere?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, troposphere

I want to use the pseudo parameter for a TopicConfigurations topics. So that I can allow the selection of a arn. How can I write a pseudo parameter using troposphere?

Topic Configuration: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-topicconfig.html

Psuedo Parameter: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be it, from troposphere/**init**.py:

```
Ref(AWS_NOTIFICATION_ARNS))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just use the name of the parameter, in a Ref() call, like so:

```
Ref("AWS::NotificationARNs")
```

I use that all the time, mostly with "AWS::NoValue" or "AWS::Region" in most of my use cases.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Example using Fn::Join, AWS::Region and AWS::AccountId to form an ARN

```
# Region and AccountId are pseudo parameters
from troposphere import Join, Region, AccountId

cloudwatch_log_arn = Join(
    ":", ["arn", "aws", "logs", Region, AccountId, "log-group", "log-name"]
)
```

---

Pseudo parameters are used with the Ref function, but each of them is defined as a separate object [in Troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/__init__.py#L517):

```
AccountId = Ref(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID)
NotificationARNs = Ref(AWS_NOTIFICATION_ARNS)
NoValue = Ref(AWS_NO_VALUE)
Partition = Ref(AWS_PARTITION)
Region = Ref(AWS_REGION)
StackId = Ref(AWS_STACK_ID)
StackName = Ref(AWS_STACK_NAME)
URLSuffix = Ref(AWS_URL_SUFFIX)
```

So they can be imported and used directly, as in the example above.